# Interactive web game for the word problem in groups?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, combinatorial-group-theory

I remember when I was in grad school, there was this website with a cool interactive game, where you were given certain "rules" (like 'abac=1'), and then you had to reduce a given word to the identity using those rules.  I remember it kept track of how many moves you made, and told you if you did it in the optimal number of moves or not.  I don't remember if it explicitly said you were doing group theory or not.  I remember the NY Group Theory Seminar page had a link to it, but that site seems to be dead now.

Anyone know what I'm talking about / have a link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The game's name is ExpaCon and was developed by Prof. Gilbert Baumslag. It is mentioned in [this blog](http://mathbrief.blogspot.fr/2009/09/game-and-movie-of-day.html).

You can apparently download an Android app - see [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/expaconandapp/).

---

Edit: [Robert W. Bell's cv](http://users.math.msu.edu/users/robertbe/rbellCV08february2018.pdf) reads

> Developer and consultant for Expacon - a mathematical game based on
>   group theory by Gilbert Baumslag

So in last resort you could try contacting him.

Comment: Yes, expacon! Seems it is completely gone though :(

Comment: @SteveD There may still be hope - see edit.

Comment: Ooh, the plot thickens - I'll shoot him an email, see what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately Gilbert Baumslag died in 2014.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, this is why I removed the unfortunate suggestion to contact him as well.

Comment: No response yet, but this definitely answers my question.  Thanks again!

Comment: @SteveD You're welcome. I'd be very interested if you get a response!